# A Regular Expression to make acronyms with word boundaries and remove characters preceding a word

Tags: regex, go

### Go Version

```
go version go1.16.7 linux/amd64
```

### Problem

I am going through an Exercise about creating acronyms and I chose to do it with regular expressions.

Some of the test cases given to me are following:

```
    input:    "Ruby on Rails",
    expected: "ROR"
    
    input:    "GNU Image Manipulation Program",
    expected: "GIMP"

    input:    "Complementary metal-oxide semiconductor",
    expected: "CMOS"

    input:    "Something - I made up from thin air",
    expected: "SIMUFTA"

    input:    "Halley's Comet",
    expected: "HC"

    input:    "The Road _Not_ Taken",
    expected: "TRNT"
```

The following code is what is able to pass a lot of simple tests where If the First Letter is capital then extract that letter and make an acronym out of it

```
 Portable Network Graphics -> PNG
```

#### Code

```golang
// Package acronym creates an acronym based on Capitalized Letters
package acronym

import (
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

// Abbreviate: creates an acronym for a full form string
func Abbreviate(s string) string {
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`\b[A-Za-z]`)
    abbreviation := strings.Join(re.FindAllString(s, -1), "")
    return strings.ToUpper(abbreviation)
}
```

The Only tests I am failing are

```
=== RUN   TestAcronym
    acronym_test.go:11: Acronym test [Halley's Comet], expected [HC], actual [HSC]
    acronym_test.go:11: Acronym test [The Road _Not_ Taken], expected [TRNT], actual [TRT]
--- FAIL: TestAcronym (0.00s)
```

#### Regex101 Playground

[Link to Playground in Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/FxT9mY/1)

### Problem

I am unable to figure out how do I compile only the `HC` for `Halley's Comet` test case and obtain the `N` in the `The Road _Not_ Taken` test case.

One of the reasons I have to keep lower-case characters `[a-z]` is because of the case `Complementary metal-oxide semiconductor` and also because of other lower-case characters in certain test cases

I could actually remove such characters such as `-` or `_` before the regexp compilation but I think that would not make my function more generic (rather hack to just past the test)

I wish to know how do I remove the characters `'` and `_` in order to make the acronym function more robust?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```golang
// Abbreviate: creates an acronym for a full form string
func Abbreviate(s string) string {
    var abbreviation = ""
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`\w'\w|(?:_|\b)([A-Za-z])`)
    for _, match := range re.FindAllStringSubmatch(s, -1) {
        abbreviation = abbreviation + match[1] 
    }
    return strings.ToUpper(abbreviation)
}
```

See the [Go demo](https://play.golang.org/p/BPpnxh2XufL). *Details*:

- `\w'\w` - word char, `'`, word char (to avoid matching `'` in between word chars, if you have issues with consequent matches, replace with `\b'\w`)
- `|` - or
- `(?:_|\b)` - either `_` or word boundary
- `([A-Za-z])` - Group 1: an ASCII letter (use `\p{L}` to match any Unicode letter).